# View columns within a HDF5 table

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

At the moment i can view each table within a HDF5 store and the data within that table.

```
with pd.HDFStore(left_file, 'r') as hdf:
   tables = hdf.keys()
   for table in tables:
       print(hdf.select('{0}'.format(table))
```

But how can i get a list of the columns within each table?

Comment: What have you tried so far and why can't you produce your desired format?

Comment: base_items is a tuple as far as i can see. so i've tried print(" ", tab[0]) will show me table names, but print(" ", tab[2]) gives me an index out of range error. I've updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to these videos i was able to advance my knowledge of pandas a bit. https://www.youtube.com/user/DrNoureddinSadawi/videos

Here is my solution. It lists the tables and their column headers.

```
with pd.HDFStore(hdfs_file, 'r') as hdf:
    tables = hdf.keys()
    for table in tables:
        print(table)
        table_data = hdf.get(table)
        column_list = table_data.columns.values
        for column in column_list:
            print(" - {0}".format(column))
```